# uncaught referenceerror function is not defined javascript android

Tags: javascript, android

I try to load html page to custom webView
also i need to load 4 javascript files to the webView,
when i put the javascript reference in the head tag in html directly, they worked well,
but when i load them at run time from my android function, they loaded correctly, but dont work and catch "uncaught referenceerror function is not defined" exception.

here is what i do in two status:

status 1: load reference directly:

this works perfectly.....

```
<html>

<head>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript" src="file:///android_asset/selection/android.selection.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="file:///android_asset/selection/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="file:///android_asset/selection/rangy-core.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="file:///android_asset/selection/rangy-serializer.js"></script>      
</head>
<body>
......
</body>
</html>
```

status 2: load from android application
in webview client,,, onPageFinished method i put this code:

```
String str =  "javascript: (function() { "

            + " var rangycore=document.createElement('script');"
            + " rangycore.type='text/javascript';"
            + " rangycore.src='file:///android_asset/selection/rangy-core.js';"
    +"document.getElementsByTagName('head').item(0).appendChild(rangycore);"

            + " var rangyserializer=document.createElement('script');"
            + " rangyserializer.type='text/javascript';"
            + " rangyserializer.src='file:///android_asset/selection/rangy-serializer.js';"
            + " document.getElementsByTagName('head').item(0).appendChild(rangyserializer);"

            +  " var select=document.createElement('script');"
            + " select.type='text/javascript';"
            + " select.src='file:///android_asset/selection/android.selection.js';"
            + " document.getElementsByTagName('head').item(0).appendChild(select);"

            + " var jquery=document.createElement('script');"
            + " jquery.type='text/javascript';"
            + " jquery.src='file:///android_asset/selection/jquery.js';"
            + " document.getElementsByTagName('head').item(0).appendChild(jquery);})()";


    BTWebView.this.loadUrl(str);
```

this print console message "uncaught referenceerror:  rangy is not defined"
although the head tag appended correctly with the scripts string.

how i can solve this problem
and thank you....

Answer (score 0):

A much simpler and elegant way to load JavaScript during runtime ist [yepnope](http://yepnopejs.com/), a small 1.7 KB library.

```
yepnope({
  load: [
    "file:///android_asset/selection/android.selection.js",
    "file:///android_asset/selection/jquery.js",
    "file:///android_asset/selection/rangy-core.js",
    "file:///android_asset/selection/rangy-serializer.js"
  ],
  complete: function () {
    alert('loaded successfully');
  }
});
```

You will have less code and therefor maybe less bugs in your concatenated string.

And the available callbacks might help finding errors or to add useful features.

Answer (score 0):

Your are loading the files in a different order in your two examples!

The order of loading script files is important. I guess you have dependencies, which could not be resolved.

Comment: You said "status 1" is working. So you should use exactly this script loading order in your "status 2".

Comment: I suggest you search in your include files for the string "rangy is not defined" you mentioned above, to find out which script is complaining. Another idea might be merging all 4 files into one (obey the right order) and test this new file in your both scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

Try it:- If the app targets LOLLIPOP or above the default web view behaviour is to completely deny mixed content. As mobile connect requires the use of HTTP during header enrichment we need a more relaxed security setting.                    `if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) { webView.getSettings().setMixedContentMode(WebSettings.MIXED_‌CONTENT_COMPATIBILIT‌Y_MODE); }`